# Session variables in laravel routes/web.php

Tags: laravel

I try to use session in routes/web.php (before Route::get()):

```
session()->getDrivers()
```

but it is emty. If i use in a Controller, then it displays the information.

```
array:1 [▼
  "database" => Illuminate\Session\Store {#1457 ▼
    #id: "XTI7mYo3jHJPS1sS1b7HCHxRL5waNrCgzzn65E5V"
    #name: "myshop_session"
    #attributes: array:7 [▶]
    #handler: Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler {#1450 ▶}
    #started: true
  }
]
```

But i want to get session in the web.php. Also php's $_SESSION is undefined. Is it possible?

Comment: routes are loaded early in the lifecycle so you won't have that information at that point ... why do you need that information in your routes files? ... and Laravel does not use PHP sessions

Answer (score 0):

I want to display urls correctly in blade.

```
@auth ... @endauth
```

is less. I want such

```
@routeisavailable('myroute.index') 
<a href="{{route('myroute.index')}}">link</a>
@endrouteisavailable
```

ideally, but @if(Route::has(..) displays also links closed by middlewares. I try to make own alternative funtions for such solution, but if somehow i can get at least logged user id (for DB::select("...id=$id")).